# Possible to spin up a local php server with gulp?

Tags: php, gulp, localserver

Is it possible to run a local PHP server with gulp? I'm using gulp-connect, but it won't render my php files. I haven't been able to google someone else with this problem, so I assume I'm doing something fundamental wrong?

This is my gulp file for starting a local server:

```
gulp.task('webserver', function() {
connect.server({
    root: '_development',
    port: 8888
});
});
```

Comment: Perhaps this will be helpful : 
[Integrating Grunt/Gulp and Livereload to existing Apache server serving PHP/Zend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22389680/integrating-grunt-gulp-and-livereload-to-existing-apache-server-serving-php-zend)

Answer (score 1):

Using the gulp plugin gulp-connect-php, works like a charm:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-connect-php