# How can I do to reload a symfony2 server with gulp?

Tags: php, symfony, gulp, gulp-watch, browser-sync

I would like to reload automatically my server symfony2 to see in real time the changes on my html pages, when I do some change with gulp,

**CASE A:**

for example:

1. Start my symfony2 server `php app/console server:run`
2. Start my gulp file `gulp` and deploy the task watch that focus on reload every change on the code

**CASE B:**

For example

1. Star my gulp file `gulp`, in this case setup the symfony2 server from my gulp file and start it when I call the command gulp, and trigger the watch task that focus on relod every change on the code.

**Test 1:**`gulp-connect-php`

```js
var connect    = require('gulp-connect-php'); 

gulp.task('connect', function() {
    connect.server();
});
/** here, please don't say me use assets, is a special requirement and is an example*/
gulp.task('productstemplates',function(){
   gulp.src( './appjs/products/templates/**/*.html')
    .pipe( gulp.dest( './web/products/') )
    .pipe( connect.reload() );
});
/** another task to watch the changes over css,less,html pages, php controllers ..*/
gulp.task('default', ['connect','another_task']);
```

What fails here, when I run this simple configurations  not works because this deploy a server over the current folder, then symfony2 server is not deployed, and I get the following

```
127.0.0.1:55669 [404]: / - No such file or directory
```

**Test 2:** `gulp-connect`

```js
'use strict';

var gulp       = require('gulp');
var connect = require('gulp-connect');
var concat     = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify     = require('gulp-uglify');
var livereload = require('gulp-livereload');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var reload = browserSync.reload;


gulp.task('appjs',function(){
    gulp.src( './appjs/app.js')
        .pipe( gulp.dest('./web/') );
});

gulp.task('app-index',function(){
    console.log("chaning something on index.html... ");
    gulp.src( './appjs/index.html')
        .pipe( gulp.dest( './web/') )
        .pipe( connect.reload() );

});

gulp.task('watch',function(){
  gulp.watch( ['./appjs/app.js'], ['appjs']);
  gulp.watch( ['./appjs/index.html'], ['app-index']);

});

var tasks = [ 'appjs','app-index','watch'];
gulp.task('default',tasks );
```

**Test 3:** `livereload`

```js
'use strict';

var gulp       = require('gulp');
var connect = require('gulp-connect');
var livereload = require('gulp-livereload');

gulp.task('appjs',function(){
    gulp.src( './appjs/app.js')
        .pipe( gulp.dest('./web/') );
});

gulp.task('app-index',function(){
    console.log('chaning something on index.html...');
    gulp.src( './appjs/index.html')
        .pipe( gulp.dest( './web/') )
        .pipe( livereload({ start: true }) );
});

gulp.task('watch',function(){
  livereload.listen();
  gulp.watch( ['./appjs/app.js'], ['appjs']);
  gulp.watch( ['./appjs/index.html'], ['app-index']);

});

var tasks = [ 'appjs','app-index','watch'];
gulp.task('default',tasks );
```

then I don't know how to do the rigth setup.

any body can help me to do the right setup or show me a right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afeter some atempts I got it, so the following is the code to auto refresh my pages when some change is detect

**1. Settup your gulp file:**

```js
'use strict';

var gulp       = require('gulp');
var livereload = require('gulp-livereload');

gulp.task('appjs',function(){
    gulp.src( './appjs/app.js')
        .pipe( gulp.dest('./web/') );
});

gulp.task('app-index',function(){
    console.log('chaning something on index.html...');
    gulp.src( './appjs/index.html')
        .pipe( gulp.dest( './web/') )
        .pipe( livereload({ start: true }) );
});

gulp.task('watch',function(){
  livereload.listen();
  gulp.watch( ['./appjs/app.js'], ['appjs']);
  gulp.watch( ['./appjs/index.html'], ['app-index']);

});

var tasks = [ 'appjs','app-index','watch'];
gulp.task('default',tasks );
```

**2. in the page that you wanna do a  change monitoring you must put it:**

The following code is dev mode.

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.write('<script src="//localhost:35729/livereload.js?snipver=1" type="text/javascript"><\/script>')</script>
```

Source: [Integrating Grunt/Gulp and Livereload to existing Apache server serving PHP/Zend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22389680/integrating-grunt-gulp-and-livereload-to-existing-apache-server-serving-php-zend)