# How to check development mode in OctoberCMS?

Tags: livereload, octobercms

I've got a `.env` file with this content:

> APP_ENV=dev

in the root of my project which shows that I am in the `development mode` 
and therefor my config files will be loaded from `config/dev` directory instead of `config` directory.

Now I want to add [live reload](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22390974/69537) to my html page by including the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.write('<script src="//localhost:35729/livereload.js?snipver=1" type="text/javascript"><\/script>')</script>
```

But I only want this to be included if I am in `development mode`, not in `production`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As luketowers answered on October's Slack channel:

> https://octobercms.com/docs/markup/this-environment
>
> So for your example you’d do something like this:
>
> ```
> {% if this.environment == 'dev' %}
>     <script src="//localhost:35729/livereload.js?snipver=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
> {% endif %}
> ```